# Yarn berry error: must be built because it never has been before or the last one failed

Tags: yarn-v2

I upgraded our project to yarn berry recently. Still using node_modules with nodeLinker: node-modules.

When running 'yarn' command i see below errors:

```
➤ YN0000: ┌ Link step
➤ YN0007: │ core-js@npm:2.6.12 must be built because it never has been before or the last one failed
➤ YN0007: │ @getgauge/cli@npm:1.4.3 must be built because it never has been before or the last one failed
➤ YN0007: │ protobufjs@npm:6.11.3 must be built because it never has been before or the last one failed
➤ YN0007: │ core-js@npm:3.18.3 must be built because it never has been before or the last one failed
➤ YN0007: │ husky@npm:3.1.0 must be built because it never has been before or the last one failed
➤ YN0007: │ node-sass@npm:7.0.1 must be built because it never has been before or the last one failed
➤ YN0007: │ taiko@npm:1.2.7 must be built because it never has been before or the last one failed
➤ YN0007: │ taiko@npm:1.3.1 must be built because it never has been before or the last one failed
➤ YN0007: │ core-js-pure@npm:3.18.3 must be built because it never has been before or the last one failed
```

I am not sure why yarn is asking to build these packages. Earlier we never used to build a package inside node_modules. How can i fix this?

Comment: I'm facing the same issue during CI. Could you solve it?

Answer (score 6):

In my project, when running into this error, prior to the `Link step` as quoted in the question above, where I was also getting a number of `must be built because it never has been before or the last one failed` errors, there were a number of warnings in the `Resolution step`, like:

```
➤ YN0000: ┌ Resolution step
➤ YN0002: │ vendor-frontend@workspace:. doesn't provide @babel/core (pa3ad5), requested by @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties
➤ YN0002: │ vendor-frontend@workspace:. doesn't provide @babel/core (p4b1ed), requested by @babel/plugin-proposal-decorators
➤ YN0002: │ (... about a dozen more ...)
➤ YN0000: │ Some peer dependencies are incorrectly met; run yarn explain peer-requirements <hash> for details, where <hash> is the six-letter p-prefixed code
➤ YN0000: └ Completed in 0s 239ms
```

As Yarn suggests in that last message, I ran:

```
yarn explain peer-requirements pxxxxx
```

where in my case `pxxxxx` was actually `pa3ad5`, the code from the first of those "`doesn't provide`" warnings.

For me, this produced:

```
➤ YN0000: vendor-frontend@workspace:. doesn't provide @babel/core, breaking the following requirements:
➤ YN0000: @babel/helper-create-class-features-plugin@npm:7.20.7 [967d5] → ^7.0.0   ✘
➤ YN0000: @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties@npm:7.18.6 [8c8ef]    → ^7.0.0-0 ✘
➤ YN0000: Note: these requirements start with @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties@npm:7.18.6 [8c8ef]
```

"npm", eh? This prompted me to run:

```
npm install
```

This completed successfully:

```
added 23 packages, removed 32 packages, changed 18 packages, and audited 1351 packages in 15s
```

But my app (running in my local dev environment) was still showing a compile error.

So I tried circling back to the original command, once again running:

```
yarn install
```

This completed successfully, and got my local app up and running again.